# Tabulator style of header filter input:focus

Tags: css, tabulator

I am trying to alter the default styles of my Tabulator header filter. I am putting in a "flatter" style per my boss's request.  so my css has ...input:focus{border:1px solid #1bb394} to change the input border to 1px green. This shows up. The problem is that on focus I ALSO get a black border inside the green border and I can't tell where it is coming from.

[image: filter with my simple green border plus additional black border]

it looks like about 2px solid black with a border-radius of about 3. I can't find the entry in the style sheet. I have confirmed that the Tabulator demo page has this as well so the style entry must be in Tabulator somewhere.

[image: view of Tabulator demo]

i think it must not be the input element itself that gets this style. Any suggestions where this style needs to be corrected to remove the extra black border?

Comment: Maybe this will help outline: none;

Comment: that was it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

user "i like cola" had the answer. the attribute i needed to edit was "outline".